# Centring table not quite centred

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

My LaTeX-Fu is weak. I've been having a few problems trying to create a table of two rows of three columns, all centre aligned, all the same size, with the main table being centred also

Here's what I have:
[image: table off centre]

Here's what's wrong
The first line ("JAM") is is centred but not aligned with the table below it. Which one is right? I suspect the table is off-centre.
Secondly, in changing colour to black the number ("0800 123456") has an line return added to it.
And thirdly, the line

> `\begin{tabular}{>{\centering}p{5.2cm}>{\centering}p{5.2cm}>{\centering}p{5.2cm}}`

is super ugly, but I've tried lots of permutations to make all cells centred to 5.2 cm to no avail.

```
% document class
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,final]{memoir}

%set pdf to print transparency properly
\pdfminorversion 7

% stuff
\pagestyle{empty} % no page numbering
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}     % no paragraph indentation

% required packages (add your own)
\usepackage[default,osfigures,scale=0.95]{opensans} %% Alternatively
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}% margins
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} % Call colours by their svgnames


% define custom colours
% Main colour for headers and name
\definecolor{ColourPrimary}{RGB}{54, 99, 169}
\definecolor{ColourBlack}{RGB}{0,0,0}

% Start The Fans Please!
\begin{document}
\fontsize{11}{13} % normal font size
\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}% HEADING
\color{ColourPrimary}

\begin{center}
JAM
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering}p{5.2cm}>{\centering}p{5.2cm}>{\centering}p{5.2cm}}
CREAM & JAM & BEEF
\tabularnewline
\color{ColourBlack}
\fontsize{11}{13} % normal font size
\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n} %normal
%PHONE
0800 123456
& spoon
& bananas
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the tabular is too large. So it is out of the textwidth. Try `\begin{tabular}{>{\centering}p{4.2cm}>{\centering}p{4.2cm}>{\centering}p{4.2cm}}`

Comment: never ignore warnings from TeX! TeX told you the tabular is too big (and so could not be centred) `Overfull \hbox (24.6186pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 29--41`

Answer (score 1):

i must confess that i don't understand purpose the most of your code ... so i limit myself only to table issues, i.e. centering of the table's cells content. for this i suggest the following:

- for avoiding to problems with table width i would calculate column width from the document `\textwidth`:

  ```
  \begin{tabular}{*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.33\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}}
  ```
- use of `color{ColourBlack}` for change of the text color in one cell cause mismatch in vertical align of text in the cell. instead of it you should use `\textcolor{ColourBlack}{<cell's content>}`

really mwe (minimal working example) with your table is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,final]{memoir}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ColourPrimary}{RGB}{54, 99, 169}
\definecolor{ColourBlack}{RGB}{0,0,0}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%


\begin{document}
\color{ColourPrimary}
    \begin{center}
JAM

\begin{tabular}{*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.33\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}}
CREAM       & JAM       & BEEF      \\
\textcolor{ColourBlack}{\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}    % normal
0800 123456                                         % PHONE
                        }
            & spoon     & bananas
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produce the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your tabular is too large :

```
% document class
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,final]{memoir}

%set pdf to print transparency properly
\pdfminorversion 7

% stuff
\pagestyle{empty} % no page numbering
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}     % no paragraph indentation

% required packages (add your own)
\usepackage[default,osfigures,scale=0.95]{opensans} %% Alternatively
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}% margins
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} % Call colours by their svgnames

\usepackage{showframe}


% define custom colours
% Main colour for headers and name
\definecolor{ColourPrimary}{RGB}{54, 99, 169}
\definecolor{ColourBlack}{RGB}{0,0,0}

% Start The Fans Please!
\begin{document}
\fontsize{11}{13} % normal font size
\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}% HEADING
\color{ColourPrimary}

\begin{center}
JAM
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{5.2cm}>{\centering}p{5.2cm}>{\centering}p{5.2cm}|}
CREAM & JAM & BEEF
\tabularnewline
\color{ColourBlack}
\fontsize{11}{13} % normal font size
\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n} %normal
%PHONE
0800 123456
& spoon
& bananas
\end{tabular}


JAM

\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{4.2cm}>{\centering}p{4.2cm}>{\centering}p{4.2cm}|}
CREAM & JAM & BEEF
\tabularnewline
\color{ColourBlack}
\fontsize{11}{13} % normal font size
\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n} %normal
%PHONE
0800 123456
& spoon
& bananas
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]